# R - For loop over large list of elements

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I have split my large data set by date like so to create a large list of several elements:

```
days <- split(df, df$Date)
```

My data has columns including time of sunrise, sunset etc. for each day. I now want to use a for loop to do further work on each day separately like this:

```
for(i in 1:length(days){
sunrisetime <- as.character(df$Sunrise[1])
# Further similar work (using time of sunrise & sunset for each date to split 
into daytime hours and nighttime hours)
}
```

My question is about the df$Sunrise on the second line - I don't think this is the right code to use when trying to access the sunrise time of each day on the days list. I have tried all sorts of variations but am an R newbie so must just be hitting the wrong terms.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's way better to act on vectors, e.g., `sunrisetime <- as.character(df$Sunrise)`. Sometimes this requires some re-thinking of your basic algorithm to avoid splitting by date in the first place.

Comment: You are probably right. But since he is using a loop I suggested a solution with a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
sunrisetime<-rep(NA,length(days))

for(i in 1:length(days){
  sunrisetime[i] <- as.character(df$Sunrise[i]) 
  }
```

Comment: There is no reason to use a loop here.